# Get specific values from a xml

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a clob xml file saved in a variable.
I would like to get the data for each Employee.

For example my code

```
DECLARE
  V_CLOB     CLOB;
  V_TEMP     VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

With data as (
SELECT 
to_clob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <Employee_Info>
    <Employee>
        <Name>Masashi Okamura</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1452-4567</Telephone>
        <Email>okamura@xmltr.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>3800</Salary>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>John Johnson</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1112-3517</Telephone>
        <Email>johnson@gmail.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>4100</Salary>
    </Employee>
  </Employee_Info>
  <TOTAL>7900</TOTAL>
  <NO_OF_EMPLOYEES>2</NO_OF_EMPLOYEES>
</ROOT>') AS XML_FILE 
FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
INTO V_CLOB
FROM DATA;

--LOOP employee records and insert in a table

END;
/
```

I want to get the first time

```
'    <Employee>
        <Name>Masashi Okamura</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1452-4567</Telephone>
        <Email>okamura@xmltr.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>3800</Salary>
    </Employee>'
```

and the second time then

```
'    <Employee>
        <Name>John Johnson</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1112-3517</Telephone>
        <Email>johnson@gmail.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>4100</Salary>
    </Employee>'
```

Could you help me please ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to use `XMLType` instead of CLOB. If you really want to use a clob, just replace every instance of "V_XML" in my example with "XMLTYPE.createXML(V_CLOB)"

I'm using the SQL XML functions here because I use them more than the PL/SQL XML functions, but somebody might have a better answer that uses those. See [the XML DB Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/title.htm) for more details on this subject.

```
DECLARE
  V_XML     XMLTYPE;
  V_EMP_COUNT NUMBER;
  V_QUERY   VARCHAR2(100);
  V_TEMP     VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

With data as (
SELECT 
to_clob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <Employee_Info>
    <Employee>
        <Name>Masashi Okamura</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1452-4567</Telephone>
        <Email>okamura@xmltr.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>3800</Salary>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>John Johnson</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1112-3517</Telephone>
        <Email>johnson@gmail.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>4100</Salary>
    </Employee>
  </Employee_Info>
  <TOTAL>7900</TOTAL>
  <NO_OF_EMPLOYEES>2</NO_OF_EMPLOYEES>
</ROOT>') AS XML_FILE 
FROM DUAL)
SELECT XMLTYPE.createXML(XML_FILE)
INTO V_XML
FROM DATA;

select nvl(XMLQUERY('/ROOT/Employee_Info/count(Employee)' PASSING V_XML RETURNING CONTENT).getNumberVal(),0) 
  into V_EMP_COUNT from dual;

for i in 1..V_EMP_COUNT LOOP
  --LOOP employee records and insert in a table
  v_query := '/ROOT/Employee_Info/Employee['|| i || ']';
  SELECT xmlquery(v_query PASSING V_XML RETURNING CONTENT).getStringVal() into V_TEMP from dual;
  --insert into my_table (my_col) values (v_temp);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_temp);
END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need PL/SQL - it can be done in SQL with an XMLTABLE:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90c521/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( value XMLTYPE ) -- or CLOB instead of XMLTYPE
/

INSERT INTO data ( value )
SELECT Employee                     -- or t.Employee.getClobVal() if using a CLOB
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '/ROOT/Employee_Info/Employee'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <Employee_Info>
    <Employee>
        <Name>Masashi Okamura</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1452-4567</Telephone>
        <Email>okamura@xmltr.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>3800</Salary>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>John Johnson</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1112-3517</Telephone>
        <Email>johnson@gmail.co.jp</Email>
        <Salary>4100</Salary>
    </Employee>
  </Employee_Info>
  <TOTAL>7900</TOTAL>
  <NO_OF_EMPLOYEES>2</NO_OF_EMPLOYEES>
</ROOT>' )
         COLUMNS Employee XMLTYPE PATH '.'
       ) t
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT d.value.getClobVal()
FROM   DATA d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90c521/8/0)**:

```
|                          D.VALUE.GETCLOBVAL() |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| <Employee>                                    |
|   <Name>Masashi Okamura</Name>                |
|   <Department>Design Department</Department>  |
|   <Telephone>03-1452-4567</Telephone>         |
|   <Email>okamura@xmltr.co.jp</Email>          |
|   <Salary>3800</Salary>                       |
| </Employee>                                   |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| <Employee>                                    |
|   <Name>John Johnson</Name>                   |
|   <Department>Design Department</Department>  |
|   <Telephone>03-1112-3517</Telephone>         |
|   <Email>johnson@gmail.co.jp</Email>          |
|   <Salary>4100</Salary>                       |
| </Employee>                                   |
```